# Bash EXIT trap with command substitution

Tags: bash

I want a bash function to start a background process and set a trap to kill it when exiting. Something like:

```
function start {
    <<<run process>>> &
    local pid="$!"
    trap "kill -9 $pid" EXIT
    echo $pid
}
```

Now, if I just call this function directly, it works, but if I use command substitution to store pid for later use:

```
local pid=$(start)
```

Then apparently this starts another bash process and the trap is executed in it right after the function returns.

Any way to make this work?

Comment: `kill -9` is a code smell. Any semi-well-behaved process can be killed with one of `-INT`, `-TERM`, `-QUIT` or `-HUP`. These signal allow the process to clean up its mess (like lock and temp files and such).

Comment: A simple possibility is to not run your command in a subshell: make it set the global variable `start_pid`, call it, and then store this global variable for later reuse.

Comment: Thanks @Jens. I'm not sure my process is well-behaved though, but I'll have a look and see if there's a nicer way to kill it.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf, I think that's a good idea. I also found this [post](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/return-values-bash-functions) that described how I can do this without committing to a specific global variable (using `eval`).

Comment: No, please, don't use `eval`! just what I said: your function globally sets the variable `start_pid` and after calling your function you save this variable (or not) for future use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally settled for a solution similar to what @gniourf_gniourf has suggested in a comment. In addition, I wanted to defer multiple cleanup operations until the script exits, so I created a single trap that iterates a list like this:

```
exit_list=()
function on_exit {
    for line in "${exit_list[@]}" ; do
        $line
    done
}
trap on_exit EXIT
```

And the start function stores the PID in a global variable (and the `exit_list` array is also global):

```
function start {
    <<<run process>>> &
    pid="$!"
    exit_list=("kill -9 $pid" "${exit_list[@]}")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading your problem correctly, you're killing the process immediately upon script exit.

This means that the process will terminate along with the script rather than blocking the script until the sub-shell has completed.

To resolve this, rather than relying on EXIT to kill the process, I would recommend that you use SIGINT and SIGTERM to kill the process.

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
function start {
    <<command>> &>/dev/null &
    local pid="$!";
    echo $pid;
    trap "kill -9 $pid" SIGINT SIGTERM
}
PID=$(start)
echo $PID;
```

Note. Don't forget to turn off any output from `<<command>>` before executing. If you don't, this will get mixed up with the PID output stored in $PID. If you do want this echoed, send it to stderr instead with `1>&2`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: My intention was to have some more code after $(start) that depends on the secondary process being alive, and kill it either when I'm done, or automatically if there was an error. I believe SIGINT and SIGTERM won't provide that.
Thanks for the tip on the command output though, I believe I had a bug there.